# Converting JS Array to PHP shows "\"

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I am posting an array to my wordpress database. The array is generated in Javascript and I am using JSON to pass it to php. Problem is when I view the user_meta table row I am presented with the following:

```
Meta_Key \"test\"
Meta_Value [\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]
```

This is how it appears in the database. Here is the rest of the code.

```
    $.ajax({
    url:"readJsonSave.php",
    method: "post",
    data: { array: JSON.stringify( array ), buildName: 
    JSON.stringify(buildName) },
    success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
})
});
```

ReadJsonSave.php

```
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");

$buildName = $_POST['buildName'];
  $myBuild = $_POST['array'];

$myBuild2 = json_decode('array');
echo $myBuild2;
print_r($myBuild);
$wpdb->insert('wp_usermeta', array(
                               'meta_key' => $buildName,
                               'meta_value' => $myBuild2

                       ), 
array( 

) 
);
```

Comment: We understand how it looks in the database, but how it should look like instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. The `wp_usermeta` table requires a `user_id` for the associated meta, which it doesn't look like you're providing.

Also, instead of using `$wpdb->insert` you should be using `update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )`.

**EDIT:** You have another issue in your code. `$myBuild2 = json_decode('array');` should be `$myBuild2 = json_decode( $myBuild );`. You're not currently decoding the post var and that is why you're getting an unserialized string in the database.

This should work. readJsonSave.php:

```
<?php
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");

$myBuild = wp_unslash( $_POST['array'] );
$myBuild2 = json_decode( $myBuild );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'test', $myBuild2 );    // Update $user_id
```

Comment: Okay made the changes now there are no back slashes in the database. Its now reads ["2","3","4","5"]. Is this the correct format now?

Comment: @Luke Wordpress serializes arrays before saving them to the database, so if you look in the database, the meta_value should be something like `a:4:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:3;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:5;}` You can check the format is correct by trying to retrieve the data. `get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true)`, this should return the original array.

Comment: Nope its displaying in the Database like this ["2","3","4","5"]. Tried to retrieve the data and all that was printed to the page was "Array" with no values.

Comment: @Luke See my edit. You're not actually decoding the post var, so you were ending up with a string as the meta_value.

Comment: Just Tried that and returned NULL Value in the meta_value field and test in the meta_key

Comment: @Luke Wordpress adds slashes to the post array (this prevents json_decode from working correctly), so you need to unslash the data before decoding. I have updated my answer. FYI Wordpress also has ajax functionality build in, so it might be worth looking at that also. [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Great took some doing but its finally working thanks for the help:D

Answer (score 0):

`array: JSON.stringify(array)` => it could be because your array was already converted to a string and you are trying to convert it again. Check the value of the array you are passing. Try :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"readJsonSave.php",
    method: "post",
    data: { array: array , buildName: buildName },
    success: function(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
})
```